# Verify value in cell is present in another range

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a value in cell `F10` that is also present in range `A2:D7`. How do I verify that the value in `F10` is really within the range specified above?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What have you tried in VBA to do this? Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/988491/edit) your question to include any code you've attempted and share what it does when you run it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the best way to use VB to solve that but you can solve it directly in the spreadsheet using the array formula:

```
{=SUM(--(A2:D7=F10))}
```

This will return `1` if the value in `F10` appears in `A2:D7` or `0` if it doesn't.

To enter an array formula, enter it without the braces (`{}`) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

To do this with a formula, you can use `COUNTIF`.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:D7,F10)>0
```

This will return `TRUE` if it is present and `FALSE` if it is not.

In VBA, you can use the same formula. Just be sure to specify the sheet name in the range references.

```
Dim valuepresent as Boolean

valuepresent = [COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:D7,Sheet1!F10)>0]
```

Comment: +1, much easier than my method. I forgot about `COUNTIF`